# How can I replace the Paypal button with a static button image?

Tags: paypal, paypal-express, braintree

Since Paypal button is loading dynamically and sometimes it doesn't show up, I'd like to replace it with a static image.

I've 2 stores: in one I'm using Magento 2.4.2 and PayPal Express Checkout, in the other I'm using Magento 2.4.2 and Paypal through Braintree.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think you should check why it doesn't show up, a button with no action will confuse your customers

Comment: In my previous Magento 1 installation I replaced the dynamic Paypal button image with a static one and the sales are increased a lot. Furthermore, I need to style the Paypal button image height to fit my design.

Answer (score 0):

Place a static image in with css/edit the template, then hide the default PayPal one using display none?